# passing controller property to component ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to pass properties to component from the controller and not the model directly. In this case the model returns an array so I have defined a controller that extends from ArrayController. Now I want each instance of the blog-post component to have a property called name which is passed from the index controller. How to pass this property to the component. Furthermore how do I get hold of individual controller later if I want to change this property for individual controller.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
{{#each}}
{{#blog-post title=title name=name}}
  {{body}}
{{/blog-post}}
{{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/blog-post">
<article class="blog-post">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
<p>{{yield}}</p>
<p>Edit title: {{input type="text" value=title}}</p>
</article>
</script>


App = Ember.Application.create();

posts = [{
title: "Rails is omakase",
body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
title: "Broken Promises",
body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return posts; 
}
}); 
App.IndexController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({
name:'Pranava'
});
```

Comment: Give this a try : {{#blog-post title=title name=parentController.name}}

Comment: Hi Deewendra, the solution you proposed doesn't work

Comment: Sorry my bad, parentController is available only when item controller is set. So in your case it should be  {{#blog-post title=title name=controller.name}}